# Is there a way to auto truncate column values while bulk insert in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

While inserting long values in snowflake we get error as :

```
String is too long and would be truncated.
```

Is there anyway we can specify to truncate automatically and proceed with insert?

I am using :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES (SELECT * FROM TABLE_2)
```

I have found this article but not work with snowflake : (https://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/sql-server/avoid-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated )

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
INSERT INTO Table_A VALUES ('long value.  ....');
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

I can use left() or substring() function but wanted to know if there is any other way.

Comment: What is wrong with the ways you have already identified? If these methods are unacceptable then what are the parameters for an acceptable method?

Comment: alternative for `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `COPY`(which much more performant for batch insert) instead of `INSERT INTO`, then the parameter `TRUNCATECOLUMNS` could be utilized.

[COPY INTO](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#copy-options-copyoptions):

> ### TRUNCATECOLUMNS
>
> Boolean that specifies whether to truncate text strings that exceed the target column length:
>
> **If TRUE, strings are automatically truncated to the target column length.**
>
> If FALSE, the COPY statement produces an error if a loaded string exceeds the target column length.
>
> This copy option supports CSV data, as well as string values in semi-structured data when loaded into separate columns in relational tables.

Comment: I want to copy data from json table to actual table

Comment: If what you are saying is that you are trying to split up the source json string into individuals fields then you are going to have to write the logic for each field anyway, so why not use left() as part of the column definition as that would be minimal additional effort?